# Using Krull Dimension, show that the transcendence degree of an affine $K$-domain is the size of a maximal algebraically independent subset

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

This is an Exercise on Kemper, *A Course in Commutative Algebra*:

> **Exercise** 5.6 (G. Kemper)
> If $A$ is an affine $K$-domain, then the transcendence degree of $A$ is the size
> of a maximal algebraically independent subset of $A$.

The transcendence degree of an algebra $A$ over a field $K$ is defined by:
$$ trdeg(A):=\sup \{|T|\ \mid T\subset A \text{ is finite and algebraically independent} \}$$

The solution Kemper wrote used Noether Normalization (in particular the transcendence basis), which is far after Chapter 5 in his book. I wonder if this question can be solved without using any of that since this is an exercise of Chapter 5. I tried using Krull Dimension, which was just introduced by Chapter 5, but got stuck by a gap:

> Let $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ be a maximal algebraically independent subset of $A$, consider $R=K[a_1,\cdots,a_n]$. Clearly $\dim A=trdeg(A)\geq trdeg(R)=n$, so it remains only to show that $n=\dim R\geq \dim A$. It suffices to show that for any chain of prime ideals $P_0\subsetneq P_1\subsetneq\cdots\subsetneq P_m$ in $A$, $R\cap P_i\in Spec(R)$ form a chain $R\cap P_0\subset\cdots \subset R\cap P_m$ of length $m$. The only thing needs to prove is that $R\cap P_i\neq R\cap P_{i+1}$ for each $i$.

It seems that this is not impossible to be fulfilled if one uses the properties of $A$ and $R$ smartly. My attempt is as below:

> Assume not, so $R\cap P_i=R\cap P_{i+1}$, then for any $p\in
>  P_{i+1}\setminus P_i$ we have $p\not\in R$. Since $R$ is generated by
> a maximal algebraically independent subset of $A$, this means that
> there exists $r_k\in R$ such that $\sum_{k=0}^N r_kp^k=0$. Thus
> $$-r_0=p\left(\sum_{k=1}^N r_kp^{k-1}\right)\in R\cap P_{i+1}=R\cap P_i,$$
> which implies that $r_0\in P_i$ and $r_1+\sum_{k=2}^N r_k
> > p^{k-1}\in P_i\subset P_{i+1}$. Since $\sum_{k=2}^N r_k p^{k-1}\in
>  P_{i+1}$, we have $r_1\in R\cap P_{i+1}=R\cap P_i$, so $r_1\in P_i$,
> which implies that $p\left(\sum_{k=2}^N r_kp^{k-2}\right)\in P_i$, so
> $r_2+\sum_{k=3}^N r_kp^{k-2}\in P_i\subset P_{i+1}$. Repeat this
> argument and we see that $r_0,\cdots,r_N\in P_i$.

So we conclude that for any $p\in P_{i+1}$ there exists $r_k\in R\cap P_i$ such that $\sum_{k=0}^N r_kp^k=0$ (For $p\in P_i\setminus R$ a similar argument applies).

Notice that since at least one of the $r_k$'s must be non-zero, we know that if $R\cap P_i=\{0\}$ then there must be $R\cap P_i\neq R\cap P_{i+1}$. So far I haven't used the property that $A$ is an integral domain, and I cannot see a clue how to use it. If this property can be used to restrict the choice of the $r_k$'s, for example if one of the $r_k$'s is $1$, then a contradiction can be drawn. Or if this property can be used to draw a contradiction directly from the conclusion below? I'd be grateful if anyone could tell me the solution or give me some hints that would work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb Z[X]$ and $A=\mathbb Z[X,Y]/(XY-2)$. The ring extension $R\subset A$ is algebraic, but does not have the incomparable (INC) property. Let $P=(2,X)/(XY-2)$ and $P'=(2,X,Y)/(XY-2)$. We have $P\cap R=P'\cap R=(2,X)R$.

If one wants $R$ and $A$ to be finitely generated algebras over a field I suggest to consider $R=K[X,Y]$ and $A=K[X,Y][\frac{X}{Y}]$. (In fact, $A\simeq K[X,Y,Z]/(YZ-X)$.) The ring extension $R\subset A$ is algebraic, and does not have the incomparable property since  $P=(X,Y)A$ and $P'=(X,Y,X/Y)A$ lie over the same prime ideal, that is, $(X,Y)R$.

Comment: This answer shows that the OP's try can not lead to a proof.

Comment: Very nice examples. Thanks.